# How to run chrome extension with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

How to run chrome extension after that?
I already added it but how to run?

```
public class asset_testing {
@Test
    public void user(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("load-extension=C:\\GUI\\distr\\chrome");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/my-app/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: So I run app -
driver.get("chrome://apps/");
driver.findElementByCssSelector("#id-extension").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"import_account\"]").click();

How switch to different window with application?

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium Does this helps you ?